# Microsoft graph 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

**Microsoft.graph Rest.Api**

i trying to get information about me from graph.api with
***https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me***

it's give me an error 401 Unauthorized error below

***401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.***

But it will work for another account this is not work only one specific account. And some request also work for same access_token for example 
***https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/trending*** worked just fine

i could not find what the differencies with this account and i also add all necessary permissions like **openid,profile,offline_access.User.ReadWrite.All etc.**

*I Also check this other topics in here but i could not find same error like me*

Answer (score 0):

i just figure it.
When i try to connect ***v1.0/me*** with **User.ReadWrite.All** permissions it didn't work because i just added **User.ReadWrite.All** and i supposed it is the same like ***User.Read User.ReadWrite*** but clearly it isn't, when i add that permissions it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you face the issue of "Access is denied" and so and while using the Microsoft Graph API, you always need to check the permission first. This type of exception has nothing to do with the programming itself.

Comment: you absolutely right, reason i is i didn't add, it worked all of other account without that permission. But this one is personel account and others are business acoount ,so i didn't pay attention to that. And i learn now think about all senarios. Thanks for the reply